# How can I broadcast the live location of an airtag on a web site?

Tags: location, broadcast, airtag

I had the idea of sharing my current location on my web site using an Apple Airtag (so I can chose when and when not to broadcast it), and was wondering what the best way would be to do that? I imagine Apple wouldn't allow that, but is there an API I could use to do that or something? Doesn't have to be an Airtag if there's another device that could do it.